# Calling COM Methods using Microsoft Detours

Tags: hook

I am trying to hook compile method of the jscript.dll located in C:\Windows\System32 which is the core of Internet Explorer Javascript Engine.

The code work fine for API Calls for example RegOpenKeyExW which is reponsible to read registery values.

But when I try to use COleScript::Compile in jscript.dll it get me an error.

this is my Code:

```
   FunctionHook* CompileFunExWHook = new FunctionHook();
   CompileFunExWHook->Identifier = "COleScript::Compile";
   CompileFunExWHook->Module = "jscript.dll";
   CompileFunExWHook->Detour = (PBYTE)MyRegOpenKeyExW;
   HookManager::Instance()->CreateHook(CompileFunExWHook);
   pOriginalRegOpenKeyExW = (pRegOpenKeyExW)(HookManager::Instance()-   >GetHook("COleScript::Compile")->DetourAddress);
```